# Can we validate data from jquery

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, sanitization

Is it ok, to validate some data using jquery?
I am working on a plugin which has repeater fields in widgets, so my plan was to convert all repeater field data in json when user clicks on save button. Data which i want to validate is zipcode and text fields.
I am not sure, if this is allowed.

Comment: In my opinion. Yes you can use `jQuery` for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can validate data using jquery before submitting form. There is a way custom way to do that by checking the fields value length

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        var field_value = $('input[name="some_name"]').val();
        if(field_value.length>0){
           return true;
        } else{
           return false;
        }
    });
});`
```

Or you can use a jquery validation library.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: HI alok, Thanks for your suggestion, but my question is, Does WP allows to validate data using jquery. I want to upload my plugin on WP repo?

Comment: Yes, WP allows to use jquery to validate data for uploading to WP repo.